# ApfloatMath.pow taking a lot of time

Tags: java, bigdecimal, logarithm, apfloat

I have to find log and later after few computations antilog of many big decimal numbers. Since log and antilog are not supported for BigDecimal numbers, for this I used Apfloat library and use its pow method which can take both arguments as Apfloat values like below:

ApfloatMath.pow(Constants.BASE_OF_LOG, apFloatNum);

The problem is I am using it in a loop and the loop is big. Apfloat pow takes a lot of time to find power which is more than an hour. To avoid this,  I thought of converting Apfloat into double and then using Math.pow which runs fast but gives me infinite for few values.

What should I do? Does anyone know ApfloatMath.pow alternative?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know an alternative, but know that asking for recommendations for libraries, programs, etc. is off-topic here. That may be a reason people vote to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using `Math.pow()` now and that some of the calls return an infinite value.

If you can live with using (far less accurate) `doubles` instead of `BigDecimals`, then you should think of the fact that *mathematically*,

```
x = Math.pow(a, x);
```

is equivalent to

```
x = Math.pow(a, x - y) * Math.pow(a, y);
```

Say you have a big value, let's call it `big`, then instead of doing:

```
// pow(a, big) may return infinite
BigDecimal n = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(a, big));
```

you can just as well do:

```
// do this once, outside the loop
BigDecimal large = BigDecimal.valueOf(a).pow(100);

...

    // do this inside the loop
    // pow(a, big - 100) should not return infinite
    BigDecimal n = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(a, big - 100)).multiply(large);
```

Instead of 100, you may want to pick another constant that better suits the values you are using. But something like the above *could* be a simple solution, and much faster than what you describe.

### Note

Perhaps `ApfloatMath.pow()` is only slow for large values. If that is the case, you may be able to apply the principle above to `Apfloat.pow()` as well. You would only have to do the following **only once, outside the loop**:

```
Apfloat large = ApfloatMath.pow(Constants.BASE_OF_LOG, 100);
```

and then you could use the following **inside the loop**:

```
x = ApfloatMath.pow(Constants.BASE_OF_LOG, big - 100).multiply(large);
```

inside the loop.

*But you'll have to test if that makes things faster. I could imagine that `ApfloatMath.pow()` can be much faster for an integer exponent.*

---

*Since I don't know more about your data, and because I don't have `Apfloat` installed, I can't test this, so you should see if the above solution is good enough for you (especially if it is accurate enough for you), and if it is actually better/faster than what you have.*